# How to parse natural language question for geoquery program?

Tags: nlp, prolog, text-parsing

I found the [geoquery](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ml/nldata/geoquery.html) program that can answer some simple questions, but I can't find any demo or instructions of how to process questions.

So my question is how can I get this:

```
[what,is,the,shortest,river,?]
```

into this:

```
answer(A,shortest(A,river(A))).
```

Moreover, how is that process done?

Comment: This is not a simple question. Parsing natural language sentences is a whole field.

Comment: Careful: you were refering to the geoquery program published at university of texas. It came from an earlier program geobase packaged by Turbo Prolog. 
There is the https://www.aiddata.org/geoquery that proposes a web api to obtain open source data. Highly efficient at doing that job, but doesn't allow you to analyze its internal processes (and hack them for other domains).

Comment: Well. I assume since the software is open source and available for the whole world, then I can ask an explanation. And thanks for the api source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers:

1. It's complex!
2. Use a library to generate a data structure from the question string (I have not tried that ever).

Here is comment I put up on the [SWI Prolog doc site](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=manual). It may be of some help.

> Start with an overview:
>
> https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computational-linguistics/
>
> In a recent heavy textbook:
>
> **Introduction to Natural Language Processing**
>
> by Jacob Eisenstein, 2019
>
> https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-natural-language-processing
>
> the author goes far beyond "NLP and Parsing" (indeed the part on
>   Formal Language Theory, Context-Free Parsing, Dependency Parsing is
>   only 80 pages of 450) and throws statistics and neural networks at the
>   problem.
>
> ## Prolog related works by reverse year of publication
>
> **An Introduction to Language Processing with Perl and Prolog**
>
> by Pierre M. Nugues, 2nd edition, 2014
>
> https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-34336-9
>
> *"An Outline of Theories, Implementation, and Application with Special Consideration of English, French, and German"*
>
> Contains an intro to Prolog, specifically SWI-Prolog.
>
> **Natural Language Processing Techniques in Prolog**
>
> *by Patrick Blackburn and Kristina Striegnitz, 2002*
>
> http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/courses/nlp-with-prolog/html/index.html
>
> **Prolog and Natural-Language Analysis**
>
> *by Fernando C. N. Pereira and Stuart M. Shieber, (Original 1987, Millenial reissue 2002)*
>
> http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/prolog-digital.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog, there is something you should try:

```
?- pack_install(chat80).
...

?- edit(library(chat80)).
```

It's a revived edition of the [CHAT-80](http://www.nltk.org/howto/chat80.html) system.
There you will find both the parser and the processor to answer your queries.

Comment: Not bad. All the links at UPenn are dead :-( The direct link to the SWI Prolog package is [this](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=chat80) Jan writes: _"The code is definitely dated. Still, it provides a nice example using Prolog for parsing, assigning meaning and querying."_ Or on github: [The classical CHAT80 natural language system](https://github.com/JanWielemaker/chat80)

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how can I get this:
>
> [what,is,the,shortest,river,?]
>
> into this:
>
> answer(A,shortest(A,river(A))).

The research at the University of Texas (over 2005-2009) is in Machine learning: Learning what the Geobase program does (published in 1988). The Prolog programs and data downloaded allows you to query its internal DB, in Prolog. The semantic parser which maps english queries into logic queries (which can be executed by the said programs) is missing.

The program comes with 2 sets of data pairs (250 and 880 pairs) of English queries and logic queries. This data is used for research in machine learning.

So if the user types in the preparsed query, you can use the geoquery program to retrieve the logic query, run the logic query and get the results.

> Moreover, how is that process done?

That is called semantic parsing. Since Alain Colmerauer's work in 1972 producing a QA application Orbis on an astronomy db, the Chat80 system in 1980, etc.

I recommend these books by Prof. Covington (taught at the University of Georgia)

- NLP for Prloog Programmers (1994)
- Prolog Programming in Depth (1997)

Available free from his [site](http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/books.html), these books will help you go a long way into NLP.